# shortcut to run current Python unit test in VSCode

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

The question is regarding Visual Studio Code (VSCode from here) and [python VSCode extension](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode) that finds and runs py.test tests.

Is it possible to assign some shortcut to run *current* (under cursor) test method and/or test class?

I really like the ability to run single test straight from VSCode, but my workflow is not optimal since it is necessary to click it and just use some shortcut.

[image: clickable run test]

This image shows the *buttons* that appear when tests are found and can be run. I would like to know if it is possible to just use some custom shortcut instead of clicking this buttons.

Comment: Is there some update on this one? Such a shortcut could be very handy.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Still using the trackpad to click it like a common peasant ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I have opened an issue to request this feature https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12218. Needs votes to be considered.

Comment: thank you @SimoneGaiarin upvotes given 

Comment: In the Java test plugin the command ID is `java.test.editor.debug` which I have bound to Ctr-Shift-D like in IntelliJ Idea to run the test where the cursor focus is. I feel your pain. Not sure if this helps with the Python, but it's certainly possible from the VSC perspective.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with VSCode 1.59 and the new [Testing API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/testing) (?) there are now these two new commands:

- `Run Test at Cursor`
- `Debug Test at Cursor`

[image: screenshot of VSCode command palette "test at cursor"]

Answer (score 6):

Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

In the searchbox, type python

All Python commands will be displayed below.

[image]

Select the command you want to add a key binding and click on the '+' button. Enter your preferred key combination in the new window.

[image]

Comment: That will open a dropdown with all available test methods within the project and then I still have to type in the method name to run it. Plus if you have several thousand test methods in your project, opening that dropdown can really take some time. Here's the screenshot of the dropdown: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rh4ys8e7zm8dma/Screenshot%202017-11-24%2009.29.31.png?dl=0

Comment: Imagine writing the test, adding some code to it, pressing shortcut to get all test methods, waiting 10 seconds to populate the dropdown, typing in the test method name any finally running the test. Make a small modification, go through this whole process again. Another small modification, repeat the dance again and again. 4 minor modifications and I've already spent over 1 minute because of waiting for the dropdown to populate every time and typing in the test method name.

Comment: @mislav, doest it help if you add a shortcut to 'Run Failed Unit Tests'. Since you are using pytest, you can also mark the test using some attributes. eg:@pytest.mark.cur_test. Then you can create a task and keyboard short cut to run only those marked tests like "pytest -v -m 'cur_test'". (You have to remove the mark once the test is passing)

Comment: Well, what if the test passes, but I'm adding an `assert` or two and want to run it again? Or if a test passed and then I changed the data; it wasn't a failed test in the last run, so it's not in the _list_ of failed tests  :-/ Or it passed but it shouldn't have :'D I hope you see how it's not the best option to use _Run Failed Unit Tests_ as a crutch to get the _current_ test.

Comment: And marking tests with additional decorators that are specific to my dev env is not very friendly to other team members who use other editors/IDEs.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Test Explorer UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer) and [Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter).

The command list:
[image]

However, `run-test-at-cursor` doesn't work for me. I use `run-file`. Moreover, maybe you should join `workbench.action.files.save`, `test-explorer.reload`, and `test-explorer.run-test-at-cursor` with a macro extension.

Comment: The `run-test-at-cursor` did work for me, thanks for that. I'm using pytest

Comment: `run-test-at-cursor` only works for me if my cursor is directly on the name of the test function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the unit test you want to repeatedly run is selected in the `Test` sidebar (which you can do just by clicking on it), I've found a keyboard-driven option that doesn't require an extension to repeat running it. From anywhere in VS Code, type:

1. `shift+cmd+i`, which for me is bound to the command `workbench.view.extension.test`.
2. *(Optional) Note that annoyingly, you sometimes have to press `shift+cmd+i` a second time to select the unit test in question (this seems like a bug to me - this happens with all Side Bar views)*
3. `Tab-Tab-Space` (i.e. Tab, then Tab, then Space). The two tabs select the little bug symbol on your test and the Space kicks off another debug run of the selected test.

Here's how the screen should look after the two `Tab` presses:

[image: How Sidebar should look after the second Tab press]

and then the `Space` "clicks" the selected debug button.

With these 2-3 steps you can repeat this unit test ad infinitum.

HTH

Comment: I've added `cmd+shift+i` shortcut to open the test workbench. But when it opens, the selected test is not the one that I'm currently working on :-/

Comment: Ah, so you're shifting between unit tests a lot? Yes, my approach is for when you want to repeatedly debug the same unit test. Gah!

Comment: It's more like: write a new test, run it, it fails, run it again (repeat n times), passes; write a new test, run it, it passes, write a new test...

Comment: so the 'repeat n times' bit will work with my "solution", right? You have to focus/select it once*, but after that `cmd+shift+i`, `tab-tab-space` will work. At least it does for me as I'm using it _a lot_ at the moment. 
*_Note_ that you can select the test with the keyboard `up` and `down` arrows so no mousing is required at all.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a lot of test functions already have shortcuts:
[image]

I also added a shortcut to get to the test bench with the keyboard shortcuts utility.

Answer (score 0):

`Run/Debug/Interactive` console in VSCode Editor ==>

1. `File -> Preferences -> Extensions -> Robot > Code Lens: Enable/Disable`
2. `File -> Preferences -> Extensions -> Robot: Variables -> Edit in settings.json`
3. need to add `"ENV":"DEV"`
4. Restart VS Code editor